# Ruby Test:Unit, how to know fail/pass status for each test case in a test suite?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testing, testunit

This question sounds stupid, but I never found an answer online to do this.
Assume you have a test suite like this page:
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Unit_testing
or code:

```
require "simpleNumber"
require "test/unit"

class TestSimpleNumber < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def test_simple
    assert_equal(4, SimpleNumber.new(2).add(2) )
    assert_equal(4, SimpleNumber.new(2).multiply(2) )
  end

  def test_typecheck
    assert_raise( RuntimeError ) { SimpleNumber.new('a') }
  end

  def test_failure
    assert_equal(3, SimpleNumber.new(2).add(2), "Adding doesn't work" )
  end

end
```

Running the code:

```
>> ruby tc_simpleNumber2.rb
Loaded suite tc_simpleNumber2
Started
F..
Finished in 0.038617 seconds.

  1) Failure:
test_failure(TestSimpleNumber) [tc_simpleNumber2.rb:16]:
Adding doesn't work.
<3> expected but was
<4>.

3 tests, 4 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors
```

Now, how to use a variable (what kind?) to save the testing results?
e.g., an array like this:

```
[{:name => 'test_simple', :status => :pass}, 
    {:name => 'test_typecheck', :status => :pass},
    {:name => 'test_failure', :status => :fail},]
```

I am new to testing, but desperate to know the answer...

Comment: What are you trying to do? As far as I remember, you could just run the files from command line, and in that case test/unit will report individual failed tests.

Comment: Save results in a Excel file. My goal is to save the pass/fail status for each test case to a Excel file. Results like `Started  F.. Finished in 0.016001 seconds.3 tests, 3 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors` can't tell details; it does tell line number that fails, but still not good format

Comment: I have test suites to include many test cases, running them individually is a way, but that still need to wrote a naive function to collect the screen result... seems detour...

Answer (score 1):

you need to execute your test script file, that's it, the result will display pass or fails.

Suppose you save file test_unit_to_rspec.rb, after that execute below command

```
ruby test_unit_to_rspec.rb
```

Comment: yes, the results like this `3 tests, 3 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors` does report results, but it is not detailed enough... unless I split each test_case individually, running them individually, using a naive function to collect these output result... seems too much work and not an elegant/Ruby way to do things...

Comment: Which Operating System are you using? if you use either Mac or Unix/Linux I will respond you how ruby use elegant way to display.

Comment: I am using this on Windows, but will deploy it later on linux. So go head with your elegant way. Appreciate it, Amit.

Comment: Here is the link that you know How ruby works

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#sec:first_tests

those tools you can also use in Ruby too (no need to use rails)

Comment: Thanks, Amit. I have been through that book before, while not go deep with the testing part. My project is no based on rails. I am simply testing the web UI of my current company, which have many Ajax driven pages. So far, I am using watir and test-unit to write independent testing programs to do the job... any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem with setting a high verbose level, in a test runner call.

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/test/unit/rdoc/Test/Unit/UI/Console/TestRunner.html

```
require 'test/unit'
require 'test/unit/ui/console/testrunner'

class MySuperSuite < Test::Unit::TestSuite
    def self.suite
        suites = self.new("My Super Test Suite")
        suites << TestSimpleNumber1
        suites << TestSimpleNumber2
        return suites
    end
end

#run the suite
# Pass an io object
#new(suite, output_level=NORMAL, io=STDOUT)
runner = Test::Unit::UI::Console::TestRunner.new(MySuperSuite, 3, io)
```

results will be saved in the io stream in a nice format fo each test case.

Answer (score 1):

What about using '-v' (verbose):

```
ruby test_unit_to_rspec.rb -v
```

This should show you a lot more information

Answer (score 0):

You can check out another of [Nat's posts](http://www.natontesting.com/2009/09/18/get-html-output-from-testunit-by-using-rspec/) for a way to capture the results. The short answer to your question is that there is no variable for capturing the results. All you get is:

> Loaded suite My Special Tests
>
> Started
>   ..
>
> Finished in 1.000935 seconds.
>
> 2 tests, 2 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors

Which is not very helpful if you want to report to someone else what happened. Nat's other post shows how to wrap the Test::Unit in rspec to get a better result and more flexibility.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, does help a little, I need more researching... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
class Test::Unit::TestCase
  def setup
    @id = self.class.to_s()
  end


  def teardown
    @test_result = "pass"

    if(@_result.failure_count > 0 || @_result.error_count > 0)
      @test_result = "fail"
      # making sure no errors/failures exist before the next test case runs.
      i = 0
      while(i < @_result.failures.length) do
        @_result.failures.delete_at(i)
        i = i + 1
      end
      while(i < @_result.errors.length) do
        @_result.errors.delete_at(i)
        i = i + 1
      end
      @test_result = "fail"
    end # if block ended
    puts"#{@id}: #{@test_result}"
  end # teardown definition ended
end # class Test::Unit::TestCase ended
```

Example Output :

```
test1: Pass
test2: fail
so on....
```